# Reverse lines in a file using simple unix commands?

Tags: text-processing

I have a file called `sample.txt`

What command should I give to encrypt this file line by line (by making the last line as first, last before as second, and so on) and store it in a different file?

Comment: "Encryption" is usually different from simple reordering. You've described the `tac` command. Can you confirm that you just want to reverse the line, and not encrypt them?

Comment: Homework? The keyword you are looking for is "reverse". `man -k reverse` should give you some ideas. If this is not homework: That's not encryption, use some tool to properly encrypt the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as @jeff-schaller mentioned you can simply use the tac command.

```
tac sample.txt > sample_reversed.txt
```

but reordering is not a good method for protecting your file because it can be simply decoded.

if you really want to encrypt your file you can use GPG.

```
gpg -c sample.txt
```

and the encrypted file will be saved as `sample.txt.gpg`

you can later decrypt it using

```
gpg sample.txt.gpg
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks a lot. It is for homework and they had mentioned encryption that's why I had specified it like that. It worked!